# Invalid property 'connectionProperties' of bean class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource]

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

I am getting this exception when initializing BasicDataSource. I want to pass Custom connection property to the dataSource.

My config is:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'connectionProperties' of bean class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource]: Bean property 'connectionProperties' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1042)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:902)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
```

Comment: I already read that post. However it's quite old and doesn't have solution which can be implemented by just changing spring config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [this post from spring forum](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/31938-configuring-org-apache-commons-dbcp-basicdatasource) to resolve the issue.

Adding this bean solved my issue.

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean"
    lazy-init="false">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="csdbDataSource" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="addConnectionProperty" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>defaultRowPrefetch</value>
            <value>1</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```